# Getting AuthenticationError while creating meeting using MS Team 2023

Tags: php, azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks

Steps taken:

- Sign up for Azure
- Go to the App Registration Page
- Created an APP there with permission `OnlineMeetings.Read OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite User.Read User.ReadBasic.All User.ReadWrite offline_access`
- Got `ClientId` and `ClientSecret`
- In the web app, create a button `Conenct MS TEAM`
- Used `$tenantId = "common";`
- When the user clicks on the button, he/she redirects to the Microsoft Login Page for the permission
- On the redirect page, I save the access token to the database.

Now a User goes to Meeting Page in Web App

- Click on create meeting button
- fill the form with the date and topic and other details
- Click on the `Create Meeting` button
- Now at this point, I am getting below Error

Do you know how I can fix this error?

Getting this error:

```json
{

"error": {
    "code": "AuthenticationError",
    "message": "Error authenticating with resource",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2023-06-01T12:20:52",
        "request-id": "34cd542e-cf5a-41d6-b331-a312136c0404",
        "client-request-id": "03c0fba2-95c1-45fa-182a-558c37ad282e"
    }
}

}
```

```php
//I rewrite the code for this issue. 

function getAccessToken(){
    $tenantId = "common";

    $client_id = "example_client_id";
    $client_secret = "example_client_secret";

    $authorize_url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" . $tenantId . "/oauth2/v2.0/authorize";
    $token_url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" . $tenantId . "/oauth2/v2.0/token";

    $provider = new Microsoft([
        // Required
        'clientId' => $client_id,
        'clientSecret' => $client_secret,
        'redirectUri' => 'https://www.example.com/msteam/azure-callback',
        // Optional
        'urlAuthorize' => $authorize_url,
        'urlAccessToken' => $token_url,
        'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => ''
    ]);

    $obj_access_token = QUERY::MODEL(); // getting it from the database
    if($obj_access_token->exipre  < time())
    {
        // Refresh Token
        $token = $provider->getAccessToken('refresh_token', [
            'refresh_token' => $obj_access_token->refresh_token
        ]);
        return $token->getToken();
    } else {
        return $obj_access_token->access_token;
    }
}
```

```
$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($this->getAccessToken());

$user_id = "Logged In User Id";
$user = $this->getUser($user_id); // Getting user details from Db and Azure

$organizer = [];
if ($user['error'] == 0) {
    $organizer = [
        "id" => $user['user']['id'], // User ID from Azure
        "displayName" => $user['user']['name'] // Name of the User from Azure
    ];
}

$data = [
    "startDateTime" => "2023-06-02T01:00:00+10:00",
    "endDateTime" => "2023-06-02T04:00:00+10:00",
    "subject" => "Test Subject Meeting",
    "isEntryExitAnnounced" => true,
    "participants" => [
        "organizer" => [
            "upn" => "Alex Example",
            "role" => "presenter",
            "identity" => [
                "user" => $organizer,
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

$graphresponse = $graph->createRequest("POST", "/me/onlineMeetings")
    ->attachBody(json_encode($data))
    ->setReturnType(Model\OnlineMeeting::class)
    ->execute();

echo $graphresponse->getJoinWebUrl();
```

### Update:

On further debugging, I found the scope had been changed automatically.

When a user redirects to the login page:
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?state=ExampleFakeState&scope=OnlineMeetings.Read%20OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite%20User.Read%20User.ReadBasic.All%20User.ReadWrite%20offline_access&response_type=code&approval_prompt=auto&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fmsteam%2Fazure-callback&client_id=fakeClientId`

The scope I attached is here
`scope=OnlineMeetings.Read%20OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite%20User.Read%20User.ReadBasic.All%20User.ReadWrite%20offline_access`

Now when the user clicks on the "Yes" button, I print the scope on the redirect page, which is not the same.

[image]

```
League\OAuth2\Client\Token\AccessToken Object
(
    [accessToken:protected] => FakeAccessTokenEwBwA8l6BAAUAOyDv0l6PcCVu89kmzvqZmkWABkAAbmqVvoIrXK2==
    [expires:protected] => 1685697206
    [refreshToken:protected] => FakeRefreshTokenP/dX4MNO9FwbJrlW+ctrB2F2iearn4AP8B+jaJv+zxN7P+dKs
    [resourceOwnerId:protected] => 
    [values:protected] => Array
        (
            [token_type] => Bearer
            [scope] => User.Read User.ReadWrite
            [ext_expires_in] => 3600
        )
)
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: According to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions), To use application permission for this API, tenant administrators must create an [application access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy) and grant it to a user to authorize the app configured in the policy to create online meetings on behalf of that user (with user ID specified in the request path).

Comment: I read that when I click on user management. It shows nothing and gives an error

AADSTS50020: User account '{EmailHidden}' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'Microsoft Services' and cannot access the application 'f98xxx6e-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-35015xxxx541'(Microsoft_AAD_UsersAndTenants) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.

Sign in and sign out not working.

Comment: Please refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/error-code-aadsts50020-user-account-identity-provider-does-not-exist